# Directly move file output of command line program to a folder

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I am running a command line program (macOS) which outputs a success message to the command line, and also creates some files which have the results of the program.

As I run this program many times with different parameters, I'd like to group the results in folders by parameters. Ideally if I run `PROGRAM [param_1 = 1] [param_2 = 2]` and then `PROGRAM [param_1 = 1] [param_2 = 3]` I'd end up with:

```
param_1_1
    param_2_2
        OUTPUT_FILES
    param_2_3
        OUTPUT_FILES
```

I have tried:

First create a folder `output` using `mkdir -p`, then do `PROGRAM [param_1 = 1] [param_2 = 2] > output` but that puts the success message in a text file named `output` and doesn't move the output files anywhere.

I have also thought of running my program and then using a bash script incorporating `mv` to move the files into folders by classifying by file name, but the file names are quite varied and, while likely possible, I'd love to skip this step if I can.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `>` only sends standard output to the file name to the right.

You could change the program itself (e.g. the way it opens file pointers), but if that isn't feasible:

- If the files are all created in either a path relative to where the program is run, then `cd` into a different directory before running, so the `mv` step is more straightforward
- If they output to a path where there are no other files, you can make that path into a symbolic link using `ln` where the real path is the output directory

Otherwise it may be necessary to do what you suggested.